# Reset Angular's Mat Data Table search filter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material-table

My web app uses a Material Data Tale (https://code-maze.com/angular-material-table/) to display some existing data. It also has various filters including the Mat Data Table's built in search filter. My problem is I can reset all of my other self-implemented filters on a 'clear all filters' button press but  I cannot find a way to have this clear the search filter and have it reset it's filtered data.

```
  // This is my data source that is used in the template
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MyObj>();

  // ... more code here ...

  clearFilters(){
        //clear other filters here

        //I want clear dataSource's search filter... but how?
  }
```

I haven't seen this posted anywhere else and doing things like `dataSource.filter = ""` or `dataSource.filter = null` then updating observers does not clear the text field or yield any results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set filter property to an empty string.

```
clearFilters(){
   this.dataSource.filter = '';
}
```

---

In addition to that [bind a model](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) to the element and reset the filter input value as well.

Template :

```
<mat-form-field class="this-is-a-class" floatLabel="never">
  <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
  <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter" #ctrl="ngModel" (keyup)="applySearchFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search by ID or Address..." autocomplete="off"> </mat-form-field>
```

TS :

```
filter:string;

clearFilters(){
   this.dataSource.filter = '';
   this.filter = '';
}
```

Comment: Like I said at the end of my question, this doesn't work. The text remains in the search field.

Comment: @JamieTaylorSangerman :  can you share your template and ts file

Comment: I was not aware that (or didn't think) you could bind the value to the ngModel like that. Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me with added alterations. After <input matInput .... > I added button <button mat-button *ngIf="filter" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="clearFilters()">
 <mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button> . Further imported the MatIconModule in my .module.ts file and added a @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"); in my .scss file to render a small cross icon instead of button.